# Why this is not a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I have G = `positive integers` and $ \mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b} = ab $ , I have to prove that is a group and the answer is no, but I don't understand why. Is because the neutral element has no inverse? Please help

Comment: Actually, the neutral element is the *only* element having an inverse ...

Comment: yes that is what I thought too, then why this isn't a group?

Comment: With the identity element $\mathbf{1}$ but otherwise no inverses, what you have is an example of a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). It can be extended to a group of positive rational numbers.

Comment: That's why. To be a group, inverses are required for *all* elements

Comment: @MorganRodgers:  Sometimes it helps to have a name for things.  The example is *not* a group, but the OP's Question and Comment indicate a difficulty in letting go of the notion that it might be possible to prove it is a group.  So calling such a thing by a name (monoid) and explaining that it is part of a group might be helpful, putting some context around the failure to be a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neutral element is always the inverse of itself. Here the pathology is that every element different to the neutral element has no inverse.

Try to check that for every $a \in \Bbb Z_+\space a\neq 1$ you don't find an element $b$ such that $ab=1$. Since there are elements without inverse, the set $\Bbb Z_+$ with that operation is not a group.

Comment: Yes, but he consider the set with only positive integer. Clearly also $-1$ has inverse in $\Bbb Z$.